# an Easy Oracle Trigger amendment

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql

I found a trigger in our Oracle Database

```
create or replace trigger pii_user_activation_trigger
  before insert on pii_user_activation
  for each row
begin
  select seq_pii_user_activation.nextval 
    into :new.id 
    from dual;
end;
```

I don't want the trigger to automatically generate the `id` each time a row is inserted.  How can I modify the trigger so that it only generates a new `id` if the `INSERT` statement does not provide a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
create or replace trigger pii_user_activation_trigger
  before insert on pii_user_activation
  for each row
begin
  IF( :new.id IS NULL )
  THEN
    select seq_pii_user_activation.nextval 
      into :new.id 
      from dual;
  END IF;
end;
```

This makes the generally reasonable assumption that there is no non-NULL default value specified for the column.

Answer (score 4):

```
create or replace trigger pii_user_activation_trigger
  before insert on pii_user_activation<
  for each row
begin
  IF :new.id IS NULL THEN
    select seq_pii_user_activation.nextval 
      into :new.id 
      from dual;
  END IF;
end;
```

Comment: @JustinCave I guess we both copy & paste :D

Answer (score 1):

Just another method:

```
create or replace trigger pii_user_activation_trigger
  before insert on pii_user_activation
  for each row
  WHEN (NEW.id IS NULL)
begin
  select seq_pii_user_activation.nextval 
    into :new.id 
    from dual;
end;
```

(note that in a WHEN clause, you don't include the `:` before the `NEW`.